# MS Access how to use a macro with combo boxes?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am trying to create a MS Access form and having an issue with creating the macros - how can I create a macro to say 'if [Album] = Selected, then select [Disks] from 'Disks'?

I have 2 combo boxes one shows the albums, the other shows the cds linked to specific albums

**Could anyone give me a link or show me how to specifically select a certain set of CD's if a certain album is selected?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going at this the wrong way.  What you need to do is to change the recordsource for the second combo based on the selection from the first combo.

You would add something like this to the AfterUpdate event of the first combo:

```
Me.Combo2.RecordSource = "SELECT Discs FROM Albums WHERE Album = " & Me.Combo1.SelectedValue & ""

Me.Refresh
```

You obviously have to change the field names and the names of your combo boxes, but this is how you would do what you're trying to do.

The `Me.Refresh` line will refresh the entire form and update the RecordSource for that second combo.